# different styles for labels inside CSS tab setup

Tags: html, css, tabs

Hopefully tis is a reallllly easy fix that I'm just not seeing, but I've been trying every solution I could find that arched even close to this in previously submitted questions and I'm just getting nowhere.

The short of it: I've got a CSS tab setup working that's great, EXCEPT for when it comes to styling the actual labels on the tabs.  It works great with a single style, but as soon as I try to introduce a secondary font style (bringing the font size down to 11px), **the right hand side of the tab disappears**.

And unfortunately I NEED to be able to have those two different font sizes/styles displayed in the tab label.  I've tried using span, div, etc. treatments but everything makes the right border of the tab go away.  Any help is HUGELY appreciated!

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wKtPL/

Here's my sample HTML:

```
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Library <div class='tab-count'> 123</div></label>

     <div class="content">
          content goes here
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Institution’s Subscriptions</label>

       <div class="content">
          content goes here
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Copyright Agent</label>

       <div class="content">
          content goes here
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-4">Internet Archive</label>

       <div class="content">
          content goes here
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-5">HathiTrust</label>

       <div class="content">
         content goes here
       </div> 
   </div>
```

And the CSS behind it:

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 550px; 
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #dadcde;
  color: #3f4b54; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  -moz-border-radius-topright:3px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
  border-top-right-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
  border-top-left-radius:3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.tab-count {
font-size: 11px;
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 

  overflow: hidden;
}
.content > * {
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform:    translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform:     translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform:      translateX(-100%);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content > * {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform:    translateX(0);
  -ms-transform:     translateX(0);
  -o-transform:      translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: So the right hand side of the Library tab disappears?

Answer (score 0):

By secondary font style  do you mean the `div` nested in the `label`?  If that's the one with class `.tab-count` you could set `float:right`.  That will keep it in the same line.

```
.tab-count {
   font-size: 11px;
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the usage of a block element inside your `label` element, which is an inline element. To fix this, change your `<div class='tab-count'> 123</div>` to `<span class='tab-count'> 123</span>`. **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wKtPL/2/)** is a demo of it.

If you want to allow block-level elements to be placed within inline elements, you could like @setek said, use the alternative `inline-block` which is a kind of hybrid of block elements and inline elements.

You should never use block elements inside inline elements, since that will cause problems like this one. What was happening was that the styles for the inline `<label>` tag were being dragged across 2 lines, since the `<div>` was taking up an extra line. That dragged the left border down a line too, which is why you didn't see it anymore (it was below the other tabs).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, firstly the `123` is being hidden under the `.content` so you need a taller `top` value.

Secondly, your labels, while being `position: relative;` are still only being implicitly rendered as `display: inline;`, so it's hiding the `123` `div` underneath the `label` itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/wKtPL/1/

```
.tab label {
  [ ... ]
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 2.5em;
}

.content {
  [ ... ]
  top: 60px;
}
```

... and muck with styling as you need.

Comment: Actually -- sigh -- I'm getting pushback from the programming guys.  They absolutely 100% have to use DIVs instead of spans for the count feature; still fixable or am I boned?

Comment: Umm I never changed your HTML, so: yes, you can continue using `div`s :)

Comment: thank you! (sorry, way tired and nursing a flu, I've really got to up my comprehension game)

Comment: That's alright :) if this answer fixes your problem, could you mark it as answered please? So it isn't part of the unanswered queue.